# FileSystemObject.FolderExists broken by spaces in filename

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I've a directory whose path contains a space (`C:\foo bar\`). The directory exists.

I can open a command prompt and do:

```
cd "C:\foo bar\"
```

And my current directory is changed to that directory as expected.

In VBS I do:

```
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim path: path = "C:\foo bar\"

If Not fso.FolderExists(Chr(34) & path & Chr(34)) Then
    MsgBox "escaped path doesn't exist"
End If

If Not fso.FolderExists(path) Then
    MsgBox "unquoted it's still not found!"
End If
```

... and I see the popup dialogs when the script runs, but should not.

It seems to cause issues with the `MoveFile` function also.

This VBS script is being executed by a VB6 service, so I can't just choose to write it in something a little more modern.

Comment: The escaped path above will not exist, as there is no path `"c:\foo bar"`. My guess is that the culprit may lie in the argument VB6 passes to the script (presumably); if it contains spaces VBS considers them as multiple arguments. But I am guessing here.

Comment: Does the service account have access to that folder?

Comment: `fso.FolderExists(path)` should work. If it doesn't, something else is amiss. Check if the account running the script has access to the parent folder of the path you're checking.